# creating a boost::asio worker thread with boost::thread under linux

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I've been using boost under windows for a while, and now have a need to migrate a couple of existing apps to run on Ubuntu 12 box for a demonstration. This app creates two worker threads, one to log incoming UDP data, and another to listen to a separate port and print that data to the screen.

I've gotten everything else to work, but for some reason the following line is failing with an error of "Invalid overload of boost::asio::io_service::run"

```
m_logThread = new boost::thread( boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, m_ioServicePtr ));
```

This line works fine on my Win32 machine, but gives the invalid overload error on linux.

There are also two other errors:

```
boost::bind is ambiguous
```

and

```
type boost::thread could not be resolved
```

But I'm pretty sure they stem from the other error. I am definitely including the boost headers, since the compiler isn't complaining about my class having pointers to IO services and Threads as member variables, it's just the line which should spawn the worker threads that's the issue.

I believe I've got boost installed correctly, as it's perfectly happy with the header locations.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is be that `boost::asio::io_service::run` is overloaded, in which case you have to [resolve the ambiguity](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded).

Comment: No, I don't think that's the problem here. I've done exactly that before without any ambiguity. I guess there's some `#include` missing.

Comment: Cheers mate, that was it. All the other issues came out in the wash once I fixed the ambiguity.

Comment: @StefanNäwe, I also found something else that could be considered the 'source'. In the migration I got the newest version of Boost, all my other systems are running 1.46, the new install was 1.51. It looks like the new overload was brought in for one of the intervening versions.

Comment: I still don't believe that... [This](https://gist.github.com/3782446) compiles without any error (gcc 4.3.2, boost 1.50.0).

Comment: ...and even [other examples](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes) do it that way.