# Invalid Overloading boost::asio::io_service::run

Tags: boost, overloading

I have been facing issues with using *boost::asio::io_service::run* in Linux, very very similar to this: [creating a boost::asio worker thread with boost::thread under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577035/creating-a-boostasio-worker-thread-with-boostthread-under-linux).

I see that the answer for that question is
"The error is be that boost::asio::io_service::run is overloaded, in which case you have to resolve the [ambiguity](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded)."

Can someone tell me how does one resolve this ambiguity for it? Thanks.

I am in RHEL 7.7, coding using an Eclipse IDE. My Code segment is:

```
std::vector<boost::thread> threadPool;
boost::assio::io_service IOService;
.
.
threadPool.pushback(boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &IOService)));
```

I get the error "Invalid overload of 'boost::asio::io_service::run' "

I see that *boost::asio::io_service::run* has two overloads:

```
std::​size_t boost::asio::io_service::run()
std::​size_t boost::asio::io_service::run(boost::system::error_code &ec)
```

I don't know how to resolve the ambiguity as they have the same return. If I try to add in a variable like this:

```
threadPool.pushback(boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run(), &IOService)));
```

I get the error:
"Invalid Arguments 'Candidates are unsigned long int run()' "
and I don't know what to do.

Can someone teach a confused idiot like me what should i do? Is it an environment problem, a linking problem or a declaration problem?

EDIT 1: Using lambdas gives the error

```
'Address of overloaded function with no contextual type information'
```

which makes no sense and I assume is merely reiterating the ambiguity of the function.

This error does not show up in the Console window, which details the results of the Make, only in the Errors window. This makes me think it purely a IDE syntax check type error? GCC version is 4.8.5.

Comment: Please post the actual compiler error.  As general advice though, in circumstances like these using lambdas instead of bind and function pointers is easier.

Comment: "Invalid overload of 'boost::asio::io_service::run' " and "Invalid Arguments 'Candidates are unsigned long int run()' " ARE the compiler errors as shown in my eclipse. If you tell me how to post images here I can show you screenshots to prove that.

Comment: Those errors are just the titles, the compiler gives other information.  And there's no need to post a picture, just copy and paste the compiler output into your question.  Insofar as resolving the ambiguity goes, the question you linked to at the start of your post has a link that shows you how to cast the method address into a specific function pointer type (rather than have the compiler infer it) - have you tried that?  Have you tried using lambdas instead like I suggested?

Comment: Sorry if I am being a noob, but if the ambiguity here is between two functions that have the same return value, I don't see how casting or using lambdas would work. I thought I should be trying to find a way to define the how the overload can be resolved when I can't (or don't know how to) declare the parameters.

Comment: The error given when 'g++ blah blah' is run also only shows the same error line without any more details, so no, compiler doesn't give other information. Using lambdas gives the error 'address of overloaded function with no contextual type information', which makes even less sense given that the lambda specifies the type.   So.... I think Eclipse is screwing with me and there's some project environmental setting I am declaring wrong or something like that....

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are seeing: https://godbolt.org/z/PdYjjxKj8.  Note that I'm using an `io_context` which replaced `io_service` years ago but has the same `run()` overloads, and I'm using `std::thread` as `boost::thread` was it's pre-C++11 precursor.  So this leads me to ask:  What version of Boost?  What version of g++?  What version of C++ are you using?  A word of advice too, this information should be in the question already!  And when you try a suggestion, update your answer with what happened.